# postgres + hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jboss6.x

I am using postgres + hibernate + jboss final 6.0.0 server.

When I try to open the database connection, it throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already
2011-10-11 04:28:06,921 ERROR [STDERR] (http-69.89.2.245-8080-11)
  at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:291)
2011-10-11 04:28:06,921 ERROR [STDERR] (http-69.89.2.245-8080-11)
  at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:108)
2011-10-11 04:28:06,922 ERROR [STDERR] (http-69.89.2.245-8080-11)
  at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
2011-10-11 04:28:06,922 ERROR [STDERR] (http-69.89.2.245-8080-11)
  at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
2011-10-11 04:28:06,922 ERROR [STDERR] (http-69.89.2.245-8080-11)
  at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
2011-10-11 04:28:06,922 ERROR [STDERR] (http-69.89.2.245-8080-11)
  at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
2011-10-11 04:28:06,922 ERROR [STDERR] (http-69.89.2.245-8080-11)
  at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:30)
2011-10-11 04:28:06,922 ERROR [STDERR] (http-69.89.2.245-8080-11)
  at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
```

Comment: Does first message (too many clients connected) offer any hints?

Answer (score 3):

Check max_connections property in postgresql.conf. By default it's 100. Increase it if you need. Also check that you close your connections.

Answer (score 0):

You have hit the maximum limit of allowed clients set in **postgresql.conf**.

You should check this configuration file, and increase the **max_connections** variable or check the **min-pool-size** and **max-pool-size** values at your JBoss datasource declaration, and set lower values to meet the Postgres configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To clear your database connections:

Start a psql terminal and:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.procpid)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME';
```